# Why is Maven downloading log4j-1.2.12.jar?

Tags: maven, log4j, pom.xml, log4j2, cve-2021-44228

I am trying to remove all the vulnerable log4j dependencies from my maven project.

I am using **log4j 2.16** dependency in my pom and have added exclusions for log4j and sl4j in other dependencies.

Still, whenever I run the maven package goal it downloads **log4j 1.2.12** jar.

```
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ Test ---
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/log4j/log4j/1.2.12/log4j-1.2.12.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/log4j/log4j/1.2.12/log4j-1.2.12.pom (145 B at 0.1 KB/sec)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/log4j/log4j/1.2.12/log4j-1.2.12.jar
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/log4j/log4j/1.2.12/log4j-1.2.12.jar (350 KB at 101.6 KB/sec)
```

I even ran the `mvn dependency:tree` command and it only shows **log4j 2.16**.

What could be the cause for it to download **log4j 1.2.12** jar?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**TL;DR:** this is not a security concern, but if you think it is, upgrade your `maven-compiler-plugin`.

[Maven plugins](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/index.html), i.e. the libraries that perform the actual work in building your project have also dependencies: [log4j-1.2.12](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j/1.2.12) is a (transitive) dependency of [maven-compiler-plugin-3.1](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/3.1), which your project uses.

You can list your plugin versions and dependencies with:

```
mvn dependency:resolve-plugins
```

The fact that Maven downloads `log4j` does **not** mean that it will be packaged with your application.

**Remark**: Version 3.1 of the `maven-compiler-plugin` is a rather old version. This version is specified in the [default lifecycle bindings](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.4/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging) and for compatibility reasons will never be upgraded. Nevertheless you should specify a newer version in your POM file, e.g.:

```xml
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.10.1</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
```

Newer version of `maven-compiler-plugin` do not have a `log4j:log4j` dependency.

Comment: Tell that to our bosses. Our company is scanning all servers for vulnerable log4j jars and we are being flagged. Dependency seems embedded.

Comment: @Piotr P. Karwasz So how can we fix this? Is there a way to exclude this log4j dependency?

Comment: @thomarkey: you don't need to exclude the dependency. Newer versions of the `maven-compiler-plugin` and other plugins do not have this dependency.