# log4j 1.2.12 dependency showing in compile logs but not in mvn dependency tree

Tags: maven, log4j

I am trying to compile the product and it downloads log4j 1.2.12 version.

When I try to see how is it added using mvn dependency:tree, it does not show up.

In the compilation logs, it says below:

```
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ jobcontroller-worker-api ---
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/log4j/log4j/1.2.12/log4j-1.2.12.jar
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/log4j/log4j/1.2.12/log4j-1.2.12.jar (358 kB at 1.6 MB/s)
```

Any idea how to know who is downloading this jar and how to change it to use 2.x version of logs.

Thanks,

Swaraj

Comment: Please show your full pom file...also upgrade the plugin version ....

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is Maven downloading log4j-1.2.12.jar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70473780/why-is-maven-downloading-log4j-1-2-12-jar)

Comment: yes, it was maven plugin. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maven compile plugin 3.1.0 downloads it by itself and you can see it in

root/.m2/repository/log4j directory in your machine

To update the version of log4j version you can update the version of maven compile plugin and then explicitly exclude the log4j 1.2.12 version

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.10.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- Compiler configuration goes here -->
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2.17</version>
                    <exclusions>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                    </exclusions>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```